# Using the buffer tool in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, buffer

I have a map that has a 12 mile buffer round it already. I have created a buffer inside the original 12 mile line (using a negative value of 9). Is it possible however to stipulate that the new buffer does not overlap the original map polygon? Hope this is clear?

Comment: you can erase the original map polygon

Comment: Maybe I wasn't that clear - sorry! I want the second inner buffer (between the 12 miles buffer and the map) not to overlap anything and also want to keep the map polygon.Thanks

Comment: sorry, I don't visualize. Could you add an illustration ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are trying to create multiple ring buffers that do not overlap, where each ring is a donut around your central feature (map).  Had you buffered your map again at the intermediate distance, the new buffer wouldn't overlap the map (but would still overlap the larger buffer).

I think you have misunderstood radouxju - the [Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000) tool cuts the shapes of one layer out of others - it would not delete your map itself. However, it is only available with an Advanced license.

Another solution would be to select the map and on the Editor toolbar click the dropdown and choose Clip. Ok your way through the dialogs (ie do not set a buffer distance) and that will cut the map out of your middle buffer. Then repeat using your middle buffer to cut it out of the larger buffer. Note you can't start with the middle buffer. Example beginning at Step 5 [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000061000000).

A third option would be to delete your current buffers, start over with just your map, and run the [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001p000000) tool.

Comment: If you want to go the Erase route, the [free version of the Xtools extension](http://www.xtoolspro.com/tools.asp) has an Erase tool that does the same thing as the ArcGIS version, but costs nothing.